# Download image file from Google Drive

Tags: android, download, google-drive-api

I am uploading an image file to the Google Drive SDK and then trying to download the same image back. I looked at the examples for downloading files from the Google Drive Developer examples, but they only show us how to download text from the files. How do I go about downloading an image? The file is .JPEG file on Google Drive.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Drive SDK documentation shows how to download files with a given path in user's drive:

> https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

I am sure you can download the images just like any other image file on the internet. Save it to device, make a bitmap out of it, etc.

Comment: It returns an InputStream. How do I go about getting a File object from that? I could try to read the bytes from the stream, but how do I get the image file?

Comment: This may/may not be what you are looking for. This is what I used to get a file (bitmap) from an image downloaded from the internet: [download image from internet and create bitmap](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/21/creating-bitmaps-from-the-internet-via-apache-httpclient/) Take whatever parts you need out of it. The code snippet there shows how to download an image file online, create a bitmap for an ImageView.