# Downloading Image from google drive api

Tags: android, google-drive-api

is there any way to download image from drive pro-grammatically in API guide there is no info to download i do not want to pin image for pin image the drive file chores prompt displays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look on google found me this:
[Download image file from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951075/download-image-file-from-google-drive)

Might be worth checking up.

Comment: i dont want to use Drive REST API

Comment: Not sure what you are on about; if you follow the answer in the question I linked you will find that there is a JAVA client library that allows to you use simple get requests through fileid.
Is there any particular reason as to why you don't want to use the provided API?

Also, edit your question to show that you don't want to use the particular API. As it stands now, you are telling us that you programattically want to use the API.

Comment: actually  google sdk provide pin option i am looking for solution something like that but i cant get media without using pin data.your answer is only way i can get data without pining .thnx

Comment: Absolutely no problem. For the next time I'd suggest you search google for any similar issues before posting on SO - or you will either not get an answer or they will mark it as a duplicate.
And try to be a bit more clear as to what you actually wish to do and add an additional restrictions.

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely.

You can use an http GET request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

You request the files resource URL.  This tool let's you test calling a live file to make sure it works.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get#try-it

Comment: is there any other way? i dont want to use Drive REST API